# Map of maps and generics

Tags: java, generics, collections, recursion, maps

I want to create a (recursive) map of maps.  That is, the value of type of the Map is another Map of the same type as the outer map.

For example:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ... >>>> foo;
```

Evidently, I need some way to refer to "the type being defined" or something in order to do this.  I guess I could do:

```
Map<String, Map<String, ?>>
```

... and then just @SupressWarnings("unchecked") myself past the inevitable warnings, but is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I feel like there are better data structures that might fit your needs.

Comment: This makes no sense ... somewhere in there you're going to have a `Map` that contains something other than `Map` objects. I guess I don't understand what it is exactly that you're tying to accomplish.

Comment: You seem to want some tree data structure?

Comment: @Brian Roach, why would he need a map containing something else than `Map` objects in there?

Comment: @aioobe - because otherwise it would be an infinite recursion?

Comment: @Brian Roach, I don't get it. Are you thinking of some special case in which no map is empty? (In that case, you could actually even have a cyclic structure.)

Comment: Erm, no ... I'm thinking that `Map` requires two things: A key type and a value type. What's the value type that stops the recursion? If you never have a value type that isn't a `Map` ... which requires ... a value type ...

Comment: *Confused*. In your first comment, you talked about objects, in your previous comment you talk about types. Java *does* support recursive types. The classical example is a `Node` in a linked list. A `Node` can contain a `Node`. Have a look at my answer for the solution to this particular problem with the recursive `Map` type.

Comment: @aioobe I agree with your statements, but I believe what Brian is saying is that you need a base case. What he should be saying is that you won't get any practical work done without a base case. The two, of course, are quite different.

Comment: Hmm.. ok. It doesn't quite make sense though. An empty map would make a perfect base case imo.

Comment: @aioobe - glowcoder actually nailed it. I understand your example, and recursive types; my initial point was more around what the OP was trying to *do*, and glowcoder expressed that a bit better than I was able to. I need to stop trying to have coherent thoughts at 3am, apparently :)

Comment: @Brian Roach - in this case I'm basically storing a tree of strings - so the "payload" of this structure is actually all in the keys.

I could, of course, roll my own tree, but this seemed to be an easy and reasonable way to do it.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, I've never used this particular type of structure myself, but I could imagine that it would be a perfect type for storing a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for instance. I'd say give it a shot. (Good question btw)

Comment: Yes, a lazy trie implementation is exactly what this is - but since Java didn't come with one, and I'm keeping this particular implementation as minimal as possible, I thought I would roll my own.

Comment: Note that by "lazy" I am passing judgement on the implementer, not referring to lazy eval or anything like that :)

Comment: Currently i am doing with combining generic and non generic like Map<String, Map> :) Nice Question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an auxiliary class or interface to refer to "the type being defined". Like this:

```
class MyMap extends HashMap<String, MyMap> {
    ...
}
```

or

```
interface MyMap extends Map<String, MyMap> {

}
```

(I don't think you can do without such auxiliary class / interface. When "recursing" you need a name to refer to.)

Comment: I said **or**... don't use *both* the class and the interface!

Comment: Thanks.  The unfortunate side effect is that it looses a lot of the benefits of collections and collection interfaces.  In the first case I need to pick a concrete implementation and stick do it, and am stuck re-implementing things like all the constructors.

The second way implies something like the first somewhere else which actually implements it, right?

Comment: Map is an interface. you can't extend it. "implements"?

Comment: @newacct, interfaces can *extend* interfaces. :-)

Comment: @aioobe: oh yeah, didn't see that. but you still need a concrete class somewhere, right

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what I did was similar to aioobe's solution, but avoids directly extending any concrete map class:

```
class StringTrie {
 private final Map<String, StringTrie> map = ...;

 ...
}
```

The downside of hiding the map being of course that the class needs to manually expose any methods which are interesting and pass them through to the map.  In my case I only needed a couple so this worked well.